# Katta Installation on Distributed Cluster

Tags: katta

Does anybody know how to install katta on a distributed hadoop cluster? I am trying to set it up, but it does not recognize any nodes which i have configured.

Here is the excerpt from the logs

`2012-10-18 18:53:32,673 INFO net.sf.katta.protocol.upgrade.UpgradeRegistry:52 - version of distribution 0.6.4
2012-10-18 18:53:32,673 INFO net.sf.katta.protocol.upgrade.UpgradeRegistry:53 - version of cluster 0.6.4
2012-10-18 18:53:32,679 INFO net.sf.katta.master.Master:118 - datanode2_bf6a0029-b1dd-4462-85a7-64ddfc89988d became master with 1 waiting master operations
2012-10-18 18:53:32,680 INFO net.sf.katta.master.Master:161 - start managing nodes...
2012-10-18 18:53:32,701 INFO net.sf.katta.master.Master:189 - found following nodes connected: []
2012-10-18 18:53:32,703 INFO net.sf.katta.master.OperatorThread:68 - starting...
2012-10-18 18:53:32,705 INFO net.sf.katta.master.OperatorThread:150 - SAFE MODE: No nodes available or state unstable within the last 20000 ms.
2012-10-18 18:53:37,706 INFO net.sf.katta.master.OperatorThread:150 - SAFE MODE: No nodes available or state unstable within the last 20000 ms.
2012-10-18 18:53:42,707 INFO net.sf.katta.master.OperatorThread:150 - SAFE MODE: No nodes available or state unstable within the last 20000 ms.
2012-10-18 18:53:47,709 INFO net.sf.katta.master.OperatorThread:150 - SAFE MODE: No nodes available or state unstable within the last 20000 ms.
2012-10-18 18:53:52,710 INFO net.sf.katta.master.OperatorThread:150 - SAFE MODE: No nodes available or state unstable within the last 20000 ms.
2012-10-18 18:53:57,712 INFO net.sf.katta.master.OperatorThread:150 - SAFE MODE: No nodes available or state unstable within the last 20000 ms.`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://katta.sourceforge.net/documentation/install-and-configure-katta
Esp. important is conf/masters, conf/nodes and zookeeper setup!

HTH
Johannes